# !dumpheap vs !strings - different count of entries and different lengths of the reported strings

Tags: windbg

Please, observe:

```
0:000> !dumpheap -min 0n100000 -mt 00007fff6c9c16b8 -live
         Address               MT     Size
0000009757e51038 00007fff6c9c16b8   116590     
0000009757e6d7c8 00007fff6c9c16b8   121392     
0000009757e8b218 00007fff6c9c16b8   160838     
0000009757eb2680 00007fff6c9c16b8   160826     
0000009757ed9ae0 00007fff6c9c16b8   179332     
0000009767e51038 00007fff6c9c16b8   121516     
0000009767e6eb08 00007fff6c9c16b8   129002     
0000009767e8e318 00007fff6c9c16b8   154506     
0000009767eb3ec8 00007fff6c9c16b8   153568     
0000009767ed96c8 00007fff6c9c16b8   212294     
0000009767f223e0 00007fff6c9c16b8   211356     
0000009767f55da0 00007fff6c9c16b8   157274     
0000009767f7c420 00007fff6c9c16b8   156336     
0000009767fa26f0 00007fff6c9c16b8   215062     
0000009767fd6f28 00007fff6c9c16b8   214124     
0000009777e71070 00007fff6c9c16b8   130594     

Statistics:
              MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
00007fff6c9c16b8       16      2594610 System.String
Total 16 objects
0:000> !strings /n:100000
Address            Gen    Length   Value
---------------------------------------
0000009767ed96c8   LOH    106134   
                SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY HIGH

                DECLARE @CommittedCommitStateId INT = (Select PR...
0000009767f223e0   LOH    105665   
                SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY HIGH

                DECLARE @CommittedCommitStateId INT = (Select PR...
0000009767fa26f0   LOH    107518   
                SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY HIGH

                DECLARE @CommittedCommitStateId INT = (Select PR...
0000009767fd6f28   LOH    107049   
                SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY HIGH

                DECLARE @CommittedCommitStateId INT = (Select PR...
---------------------------------------
4 matching strings
```

Notice, that `!dumpheap` reports 16 live strings, whereas `!strings` reports only 4.

And their lengths are different.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the answer.

The 4 strings found both by `!strings` and by `dumpheap` have different lengths depending which command is used:

```
Address            Length by !dumpheap   Length by !strings         
0000009767ed96c8   212294                106134   
0000009767f223e0   211356                105665
0000009767fa26f0   215062                107518
0000009767fd6f28   214124                107049
```

Where:

```
212294 = 106134 * 2 + 26
211356 = 105665 * 2 + 26
215062 = 107518 * 2 + 26
214124 = 107049 * 2 + 26
```

So, here is my hypothesis - `!dumpheap` reports the raw size of the .NET strings - meaning it doubles the count of the characters and adds up any extra fields of the string object. The `!strings` commands just returns the count of the characters in the strings.

Comment: Wow. I didn't expect that. Nice conclusion.